# Worklight appcenter Log

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, maximo-anywhere

I working using Maximo  Anywhere 7.5.1
 when i am trying to login using the default app -Work Execution- the application didnt login and i got the following exception in Work-light Server Log

```
> [7/7/15 1:37:05:093 GST] 0000008a SystemErr     R java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
[7/7/15 1:37:05:102 GST] 0000008a SystemErr     R   at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:412)
[7/7/15 1:37:05:102 GST] 0000008a SystemErr     R   at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:271)
[7/7/15 1:37:05:103 GST] 0000008a SystemErr     R   at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:258)
[7/7/15 1:37:05:103 GST] 0000008a SystemErr     R   at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:376)
[7/7/15 1:37:05:103 GST] 0000008a SystemErr     R   at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:546)
[7/7/15 1:37:05:103 GST] 0000008a SystemErr     R   at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:495)
[7/7/15 1:37:05:103 GST] 0000008a SystemErr     R   at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
[7/7/15 1:37:05:103 GST] 0000008a SystemErr     R   at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:437)
[7/7/15 1:37:05:103 GST] 0000008a SystemErr     R   at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:551)
[7/7/15 1:37:05:103 GST] 0000008a SystemErr     R   at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:227)
[7/7/15 1:37:05:103 GST] 0000008a SystemErr     R   at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:313)
[7/7/15 1:37:05:103 GST] 0000008a SystemErr     R   at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:332)
[7/7/15 1:37:05:104 GST] 0000008a SystemErr     R   at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:999)
[7/7/15 1:37:05:104 GST] 0000008a SystemErr     R   at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:935)
[7/7/15 1:37:05:104 GST] 0000008a SystemErr     R   at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:853)
[7/7/15 1:37:05:104 GST] 0000008a SystemErr     R   at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1207)
[7/7/15 1:37:05:104 GST] 0000008a SystemErr     R   at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:390)
[7/7/15 1:37:05:104 GST] 0000008a SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.tivoli.si.auth.TpaeCustomLoginModule.authenticate(Unknown Source)
[7/7/15 1:37:05:104 GST] 0000008a SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.tivoli.si.auth.TpaeCustomLoginModule.login(Unknown Source)
[7/7/15 1:37:05:104 GST] 0000008a SystemErr     R   at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.LoginContext.invokeLoginModule(LoginContext.java:236)
[7/7/15 1:37:05:104 GST] 0000008a SystemErr     R   at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.LoginContext.processRequest(LoginContext.java:200)
[7/7/15 1:37:05:104 GST] 0000008a SystemErr     R   at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationContext.processRequest(AuthenticationContext.java:274)
[7/7/15 1:37:05:105 GST] 0000008a SystemErr     R   at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:148)
[7/7/15 1:37:05:105 GST] 0000008a SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
[7/7/15 1:37:05:105 GST] 0000008a SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
[7/7/15 1:37:05:105 GST] 0000008a SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:960)
[7/7/15 1:37:05:105 GST] 0000008a SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1064)
[7/7/15 1:37:05:105 GST] 0000008a SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3878)
[7/7/15 1:37:05:105 GST] 0000008a SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
[7/7/15 1:37:05:105 GST] 0000008a SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:981)
[7/7/15 1:37:05:105 GST] 0000008a SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
[7/7/15 1:37:05:105 GST] 0000008a SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
[7/7/15 1:37:05:105 GST] 0000008a SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:461)
[7/7/15 1:37:05:105 GST] 0000008a SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:528)
[7/7/15 1:37:05:106 GST] 0000008a SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:314)
[7/7/15 1:37:05:106 GST] 0000008a SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
[7/7/15 1:37:05:106 GST] 0000008a SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
[7/7/15 1:37:05:106 GST] 0000008a SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
[7/7/15 1:37:05:106 GST] 0000008a SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
[7/7/15 1:37:05:106 GST] 0000008a SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
[7/7/15 1:37:05:106 GST] 0000008a SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
[7/7/15 1:37:05:106 GST] 0000008a SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
[7/7/15 1:37:05:106 GST] 0000008a SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
[7/7/15 1:37:05:106 GST] 0000008a SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1864)
```

Comment: Can you please decide? are you asking about appcenter or worklight? not the same server.

Answer (score 0):

A Worklight application will not be trying to communicate with the AppCenter Server. It will only try to communicate with the Worklight Server. So, your question makes no sense... please put some more effort when asking questions and properly describe your scenario.

Additionally, `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect` typically refers to a network error, such as pointing to the wrong server, port, etc...

I suggest that you will double-check where to you are pointing your application, and again - better describe what you've done.

Comment: Thank you i found the issue  
its network issue on maximo server